# Safari javascript cookie issue

Tags: javascript, cookies, safari

I've hit a bit of a weird issue in Safari in regards to setting a js cookie. The cookie itself is just a rgb colour value, which gets set using `.click()`, and is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, yet in Safari the value of the cookie is incomplete, showing up as `rgb(193` instead of `rgb(193, 184, 76)` as the other browsers do.

The jQuery function I'm using to set the cookie is:

```
$('.project_link a').click(function() {
    var link_colour = $(this).css("color");
    document.cookie = "colour="+link_colour+";expires=;path=/";
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `encodeURIComponent` to encode the "link_colour" value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its truncating at the comma. Same thing can happen with semi-colons.
Encode it with something like encodeURIComponent.